# mocking a method using Moq framework doesn't return expected result

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq, mstest

I have a class library , which has 2 classes and one Interface as below.
Main Class:

```
    public class Class1 
    {
        int a=5 ,b=9;
        private Interface1 iHelper;
        public Class1(Interface1 _inter)
        {
            iHelper = _inter;
        }
        public int getData()
        {
            int result = iHelper.AddNumbers(a, b);
            return result;
        }

    }
```

HelperClass Class :

```
class HelperClass : Interface1
    {
        public int AddNumbers(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
```

Interface :

```
public interface Interface1
    {
        int AddNumbers(int a, int b);
    }
```

Now, I'm trying to test the method `getData()`. I have mocked `AddNumbers` method using `Moq` , as shown below.

```
[TestMethod()]
public void getDataTest()
{
     int a = 3, b = 5;
     int c = 8;
     var mockService = new Mock<Interface1>();
     mockService.Setup(x => x.AddNumbers(a,b)).Returns(c);

     Class1 obj = new Class1(mockService.Object);
     var result = obj.getData();
     int final = result;
 }
```

When I debug this test, it is returning value 0.
As I understand when we mock any method, it has to return the mocked value while testing. In this case I have mocked the return value of `AddNumbers` method to 8. So it should return 8.But instead , it is returning 0.

Can anyone explain me what am I doing wrong.

**EDIT** : In reality , the values of `a` and `b` in Class1 are dynamic . In the sample code I have hardcoded it. And also , I do not want to test `AddNumbers` method. I want it to return some fixed value no matter what. In this case, i want it to return 8.

Comment: The values of a and b are dynamic in reality. So please don't go with the hardcoded values.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion, I have edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You specify the call to `AddNumbers` in your mock expectation with explicit numbers. Only when these explicit values are given to `AddNumbers` will 8 be returned. If you do not care about the actual parameters to `AddNumbers` you need to specify your expectation in a way that the parameters are ignored (e.g. via `It.IsAny<>`)

```
mockService.Setup(x => x.AddNumbers(It.IsAny<int>(),It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(c);
```

Also see https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart section "Matching Arguments".

Answer (score 4):

Because in `Class1` variables `a` and `b` differ from variables defined in `getDataTest`. Use the same values:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void getDataTest()
{
     int a = 5, b = 9; // here
     int c = 14; // and here
     var mockService = new Mock<Interface1>();
     mockService.Setup(x => x.AddNumbers(a,b)).Returns(c);

     Class1 obj = new Class1(mockService.Object);
     var result = obj.getData();
     int final = result;
 }
```

Comment: In reality,in Class1, the values of a and b are dynamic in nature. I hardcoded it here in the sample code. I do not want to test the AddNumbers method , so I'm mocking it. So I'm just taking 2 values for a and b and returning the value 8 no matter what the actual values of a and b are in Class1.

Comment: Mock is very literal about its arguments.  If you tell it that calling the function with `5` and `9` returns `14`.  That function is *only* mocked for `5` and `9`.  No other combinations will have an implementation.  You can tell it to implement with any value using the special values in `It`.